# Best way to detect characters not belonging to Windows-1252

Tags: java

I have a service that receives free text, such as name, surname, address, etc. and I want to throw an error if one of the characters sent doesn't belong to the windows 1252 character set but I don't know how to do so in a proper way. What I was thinking about is a regex, but not sure if that is the best option.

The regex would be the [letters from cp1252](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-cp1252/) with any other letter `\\w`, so, something like this:

```
String test = "ŠŒŽšœžŸÀÁÂÃ ÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝ Þßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïð ñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ asvsdf QWESA 1234 ÜüËëÄäÖö";
System.out.println(test.matches("[ŠŒŽšœžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ\\w"
        + "\\d\\s\\.]+"));
```

I don't need to detect the encoding itself, only if it doesn't belong to the charset.

Comment: *I don't need to detect the encoding itself, only if it doesn't belong to the charset.* What *is* the encoding?

Comment: It is UTF-8 in local

Comment: Right. Something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#canEncode(char)) should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion as code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

public class Windows1252Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Can we encode the incoming UTF-8 (per OP) as Windows-1252?
            Charset cs = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");
            CharsetEncoder enc = cs.newEncoder();
            System.out.printf("Can charset %s encode sequence %s? %b%n", cs, args[0], enc.canEncode(args[0]));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the heated discussion. This seems to be the neater of the proposed solutions since it is easy to read and maintainable. As I said, I was going with a regex since I don't have much experience with encoding initially, so, this is a huge leap :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if its Unicode code point is outside the range of 0x20 to 0x7E AND 0xA0 to 0xFF, which covers all of the printable ASCII characters and the extended characters in the Windows 1252 character set, excluding the EN dash. Something like this:

```
String input = "any text goes here";

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (c < 0x20 || (c > 0x7E && c < 0xA0) || c > 0xFF && c != '\u2013') 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character at index " + i + " does not belong to the Windows 1252 character set: " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't cut it. Take as one case `™`. The codepoint of that is U+2122 yet is part of the WIndows-1252 charset. That of course, is beyond your loop end, which cuts off a significant part of the charset. What made you stop it there?

Comment: Okay, let me explain it deeply: The Windows 1252 character set, also known as Windows Western. The range of characters can be: 0x00 to 0x1F: Control characters, 0x20 to 0x7E: Printable ASCII characters, 0x80 to 0x9F: Control characters (in the C1 range) and 0xA0 to 0xFF: Extended characters. 

Maybe you need to include the Extended chars.

Comment: Feel free to rewrite the code. The input data might, say, include a en dash in an address - part of the Windows-1252 charset

Comment: Already done :) - Just a && increment with the extended chars list.

Comment: For my last example, it would throw an exception with a false message for en dash (0x2013)

Comment: Just updated the code to handle the dash. You can keep including any character at the if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250792/discussion-between-methark-and-g00se).

Comment: Do you want parentheses around `code > 0xFF && c != '\u2013'`?

Comment: The code is working like a charm here. There was I typo on the variables names but I just fixed.

Comment: 26 others to do, in addition to the En Dash

Comment: Problem that this is conflating bytes and characters. You should encode to bytes, and then perform the ops.